# Stop list from being static in parent class

Tags: python, list, inheritance

I have the following code

```
class device(object):
  triggerphrases=[]
  visActive=False
  
  def addTrigger(self,phrase):
    self.triggerphrases.extend([phrase])
  
  def SetActive(self,On):
    self.visActive=On
    
  def isActive(self):
    return self.visActive

class light(device):
  
  def setPhrase(self):
    super().addTrigger("living room light")
  
  def printPhrases(self):
    print(super().triggerphrases)
       
class colouredLight(device):
  
  def setPhrase(self):
    super().addTrigger("coloured light")
    
  def printPhrases(self):
    print(super().triggerphrases)
    
firstlight=light()
firstlight.setPhrase()
firstlight.SetActive(True)
print(firstlight.isActive())


secondlight=colouredLight()
secondlight.setPhrase()


secondlight.printPhrases()
print(secondlight.isActive())
```

What is strange is that the visactive is tied to the instance where as the triggerphrases acts statically so the output I get is.

```
True
['living room light', 'coloured light']
False
```

What I would like to happen is that the list was tied to the instance and so one object would return ['living room light'] and the other ['coloured light']. I know I could hold the list at the subclass level but that would defeat the object of having the code in one place. This is a simplified version - the real thing would have many different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `__init__` on the parent class and move the variables inside so they are instance variables:

```
class device(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.triggerphrases = []
        self.visActive = False

    def addTrigger(self, phrase):
        self.triggerphrases.extend([phrase])

    def SetActive(self, On):
        self.visActive = On

    def isActive(self):
        return self.visActive


class light(device):

    def setPhrase(self):
        super().addTrigger("living room light")

    def printPhrases(self):
        return self.triggerphrases


class colouredLight(device):

    def setPhrase(self):
        super().addTrigger("coloured light")

    def printPhrases(self):
        return self.triggerphrases



firstlight = light()
firstlight.setPhrase()
firstlight.SetActive(True)
print(firstlight.printPhrases())
print(firstlight.isActive())


secondlight = colouredLight()
secondlight.setPhrase()
print(secondlight.printPhrases())
print(secondlight.isActive())
```

Output:

```
['living room light']
True
['coloured light']
False
```